# Jobs vs script: What is their difference in Travis-CI?

Tags: travis-ci

It seems that I can put commands, such as echo "helloworld", in `script` or in `jobs` section of `.travis.yml`. What is their difference?

Answer (score 0):

They are completely different functionality defined in `.travis.yml`

`script:` is a build/job phrase that you run commands in this specific step. [1]

`job:` is a step where you will be able to define multiple ones within `.travis.yml` file and each `job` can run an additional build job that you can define their own `script` inside it. [2]

[1]https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/job-lifecycle/#the-job-lifecycle

[2]https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-matrix/#listing-individual-jobs